# Parse mathematical expression

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am designing an app which will have user input a complex math expression involving all sorts  of mathematical operations(sin, cos, ln, factorial, power etc.).
The user will see the expression in a textblock and it will be parsed later for further operations.

Now, this parsing part is where I am stuck. I want the expression in my code.

e.g. If user inputs sin(x)+cos(x), i want to be able to actually perform this operation for some value of x in my code.

I know there are a lot of similar questions out there. But, I want something specific to windows phone SDK.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look on [CodeDom Calculator - Evaluating C# Math Expressions dynamically](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/CodeDomCalculator08082005003253AM/CodeDomCalculator.aspx). This is basically a class that enables you to eval the math expression and not only.